# Why is when i do put request using Django rest framework I got 200 but when i try to see one of fields it shows null using get request not the put one

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was trying to do put request on Postman and it's successful, but when I try the get method to get same result one of the fields which is `car_year` shows `null`.

````
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import Driver
from .serializers import DriverSerializer
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import mixins

from rest_framework.views import APIView



# Create your views here.


class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.CreateModelMixin,mixins.UpdateModelMixin,mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class = DriverSerializer
    queryset = Driver.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self,request,id=None):
        if id:
            return  self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return self.list(request)

    def post(self,request):
        return self.create(request)

    def put(self,request,id=None):
        return self.update(request,id) 



from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Driver(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone_number=models.IntegerField(max_length=None)
    car_model=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    car_year=models.IntegerField(max_length=None)

    def  __str__(self):
return self.name

    



from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Driver



class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Driver
        fields=['id','name','email','phone_number','car_model','car_year'] ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using that very `GenericAPIView` class that you've made, look into using a [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset). Besides that, you are missing the `permissions_classes` in your APIView.

Try this:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions

class DriverViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Driver.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DriverSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Also, your serializer looks fine.

`car_year` and `phone_number` are `IntegerFields` and you've set the `max_length` on them. That `max_length=None` should be removed.

Try the things I mentioned and it should would fine. I'm guessing it's most likely the view you are using but it could also be the integer field.

Also, if this is going to be a production app, the `phone_number` field shouldn't be an integer but rather a string, or better yet, you can use the [django-phonenumber-field](https://django-phonenumber-field.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.